# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I have seen similar posts, but I can't seem to apply those answers to my problem. I am not able to see exactly what I am doing wrong here.
I need to print each of 5 scores, and their total.

```
for i in range(5):
    arrow = win.getMouse()
    score = findScore(arrow)
    print('Current Shot: {:}'.format(score))
    total = total + score
    print('Total: {:}'.format(total))
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who may be able to help.

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate (either of how it was marked before, or how I tried to clean it up), but it *is* a simple typo that should have been closed as such. Voting to delete.

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration of your `for` loop you are referencing `total` in the line `total = total + score` before your program knows what total is. Initialize it ahead of time with `total = 0` before your `for` loop. If you are providing an initial value for `total` in earlier code, make sure that this code is actually run.